# Parallax Scrolling Header with Tabs in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parallax

I am trying to create Parallax Scrolling Header with Tabs in iOS .

[image]

1. i found few Library which provide the Parallax Header With `TableView` .
2. I am Trying to reduce the height of Header View According to the Content off set of `TablView`  below  in the pageViewController using delegate but now Working .

My Problem is i am not able to find any way to Add Parallax header with PageViewController , How can i create this Desired View .

Does anyone have done this is ios , ?

Comment: Take outer scrollview - > Add One UIView(container view) with height = header + self.view --> Add header view + UItableview inside container view

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution for this one? @Dhiru